# building a has_one relation with devise user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Im new to rails and am having difficulty creating a profile by a devise user

here is the ProfileController:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

def index
 @profiles = Profile.all
end

def new
 @profile = current_user.build_profile
end

def create
@profile = current_user.build_profiles(profile_params)
redirect_to profiles_path
end

def show

end

def edit

end

def update
@profile.update(profile_params)
redirect_to(profiles_path(@profile))
end

def destroy
@profile.destroy
redirect_to profiles_path
end

private
def profile_params
params.require(:profile).permit(:university, :degree)
end

def set_profile
@profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

When i run the rails server i can submit the form but nothing is getting stored in the model 'Profile'

here is the index.html.erb where the data should appear:

```
<h2>profiles</h2>

<% @profiles.each do |profile| %>

  <%= link_to profile do %>
    <%= profile.university %>
  <% end %>
    <%= profile.degree %>

<% end %>
```

user.rb file:

```
has_one :profile
```

and the profile.rb file:

```
belongs_to :user
```

nothing seems to be getting saved to the profile model and nothing is getting displayed on the index.html.erb. Also i have created a migration to store user_id in the profile model.

Thank for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By far the *best* way to create a `profile` for a `user` is to build it when the `User` object is created:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile
   before_create :build_profile
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end

#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This will build a blank `profile` each time a new `user` is created. It means that each user will *only* ever have **one** profile, which they'll be able to populate & edit.

---

In regards your issue, there are several points:

1. Don't list "profiles" with an index, list users & pull their profile data
2. If managing a profile, nest it under the associative user model

Here's how to do that:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: :index
resource :profile, only: [:show, :update]

#app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
   def show
   end

   def update
      redirect_to :show if current_user.update profile_params
   end

   private

   def profile_params
      params.require(:user).permit(profile_attributes: [:name])
   end
end

#app/views/profiles/show.html.erb
<%= form_for current_user, url: profile_path do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :profile do |p| %>
      <%= p.text_field :name %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Update**

My post above is exactly what we do.

The way it works is very simple -- when a `User` is created (IE they have gone to the trouble of filling out their details), the Rails backend automatically creates a *blank* `Profile` object.

This does several things:

> 1. Always makes sure you have a `Profile` for each user (you don't have to go to the bother of making them "create" a profile).
> 2. Gives you the ability to validate only inputted data on a created `Profile` (*not* having to guess whether it's already been done).

--

If you're getting *undefined method `build_profile`*, it means your associations are incorrect.

All singular associations have [`build_[association]`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Auto-generated+methods) as defined instance methods. The code I provided fires `build_profile` for a `has_one` association. The only time it would be "undefined" would be if the association was plural

--

**Update**

[image]

This suggests a routing error.

Considering it appears at `root`, I think the problem is [here](https://github.com/gurmukhsinghdavgun/has_oneProfile/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb#L12):

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path %>
```

You don't have `edit_profile_path` -- it should just be `profile_path`

Comment: the above code does not seem to work, in the application the user first signs up, and then should be redirected to the profile#new page to create the profile rather than a profile being built when a user is created

Comment: It's a better pattern than what you're suggesting. If a user `has_one :profile`, surely that profile should be created *with* the `User` object? If not, you have an antipattern (what if user chooses *not* to create a `profile`? Does this not mean the profile will not exist?)

Comment: I understand the logic of what your saying, but I'm getting a error "undefined method `user_path' " when i try to fill the form to update the fields in profile#update

Comment: Okay that's because we're using a `User` object; we'll need to define the url (Updated)

Comment: The problem is that nothing is actually getting saved besides the user, all the values :university and :degree for example are nil?

Comment: Yes that's the point. When you build a blank profile, the profile has no values. Then, when you redirect the user to the `edit` action, he can input the values as required

Comment: sorry to keep bugging you but, the solution does not seem to work, even when directed to the edit page, i enter the values but nothing. I used the rails console to check what was getting stored and I'm getting a userid but nil value for the other fields

Comment: Want to go to chat about it to get it fixed?

Comment: How long are you staying online for? I'll be able to chat in 10 minutes

Comment: I'll be on later tonight, im happy to come on when your available, again thanks for your help

Comment: No problem! give me a comment on here and we can go to chat

Comment: Im available now if you are free? (I'm not sure how this chat works tho :|)

Comment: I'll open a chat room for us

Comment: I can't talk on chat because i need 20 rep :(

Comment: I can join but can't type anything and get a message......i really do appreciate your effort and help!, il have to try figure it out some other way. Thank Again

Comment: if you write an answer on here, I'll upvote it so you can chat

Comment: as a learning reference (lets ignore whether its an anti-pattern) how would i, in my current solution build the profile associated with the user and display it? i know that using a has_one relation uses different syntax to has_many. As i used current_user.build_profile, but i get undefined method `build_profile ?

Comment: Have you got a github repo I could look at?

Comment: here a link https://github.com/gurmukhsinghdavgun/has_oneProfile.git , again I'm trying but I'm not getting the right result, i wrote in the wiki what I'm trying to do, Again thanks you so much

Comment: No problem, let me check

Comment: Okay your code looks good. Can you show me a screenshot of the `undefined method` error?

Comment: thanks for the update, The data is getting saved but getting an error in the update method in the profile controller ? image - http://postimg.org/image/5zi50fcwt/

Comment: Change that line to `redirect_to profile_path if current_user.update profile_params`

Comment: thanks worked, the data is getting stored, how do i display this data back on the page? at the moment the profile#show page is where all the updating happens, it would be ideal to show the users actual profile data here. In the profile_controller in the show method i tried something like @profile = user.profile.find(params[:id])? but no success

Comment: You can just put `current_user.profile.x` in any of the actions you have and it will show up the values you've set

Answer (score 0):

It needs a save call for the profile which you build in crate method.
e.g.

```
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
     redirect_to root_url 
  else
     render :new 
  end
end
```

if condition checks is data save correct or not. And change example's User model to your Profile model

BTW, just careful with the plural, I think it should use 'build_profile' instead 'build_profiles'